How to create a custom component for a tag with attributes in markdoc using angular?
I am trying to create dynamic elements within markdown content using markdoc. I tried the ngx-markdoc package but I had issues with setting up provideMarkdocOptions in the provider. So I tried to used the base markdoc package as a standalone component and it works but I am not able to figure out how to render custom components with the config file.

Can you please check about the markdoc in the below link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@notiz/ngx-markdoc

I tried this but I couldnt find how to render custom components
